# Failed to negotiate Xamarin forms with SignalR (.NET framework)

Tags: xamarin.forms, signalr, .net-framework-version, signalr.client

I am using Xamarin Forms project with SignalR, that's hosted on IIS (on a public server).

Same as [project in this link](https://medium.com/@edgarleonardo/websockets-implementation-with-signalr-and-xamarin-forms-d9244fa128da).

When I ran this project, it worked correctly, but when I merged this code in my project, it failed on the negotiation function.

Also, I noticed that parameter "connectiondata" is "{[]}" but in a demo, connection data has hub name.
I am using package [Microsoft.AspNet.Signalr.Client 2.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/2.2.2) in my application.

My application and demo connected on same URL.

Comment: Could you provide the code you have at the moment?

Comment: HubConnection _connection;
var http = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient();
await _connection.Start(new WebSocketTransportLayer(http));
i have WebSocketTransportLayer class that implement IClientTransport interface
and i have this function on this class :
public async Task<NegotiationResponse> Negotiate(IConnection connection, string connectionData)
above connection data come with empty as i mentioned in my code but come with hub name in demo

Comment: this is the old SignaR, use the new Core version : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Try to use the latest version signalR 2.0 using Package Manager Console command:

`install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT am using signalr(2.2.2) also i tried it with(2.3.0)with xamarin forms i am trying to initiate signalr connection to connect to signalr hub but signalr send negotiate url without hub name.HubConnection _connection=new HubConnection("MyURL");IHubProxy _proxy =_connection3.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");var http=new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient();await _connection.Start();connection to url send with empty hub name like that:"MyURL/ChatWebServerWithSignalR/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=[{}]&noCache=d6ea8f35-4dbb-48ee-a83e-cfba2fd2859c"

Comment: I also had issues with the old package and switched completely to the new .net core version which works fine.